# Why is "master" required in git pull --rebase origin master but not git rebase -i origin?

Tags: git, rebase, git-interactive-rebase

When I want to rebase against remote master, I use

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

If I use

```
git pull --rebase origin
```

I receive the error

```
You asked to pull from the remote 'origin', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.
```

But why is it that

```
git rebase -i origin
```

works?

And in this case

```
git rebase -i origin master
```

actually results in

```
fatal: fatal: no such branch/commit 'master'
```

I have no local branch named master, but why is it not going to the remote branch in this case?

Comment: The short answer is because the syntax of those commands is different. ;) For rebase you should use `git rebase origin/master` and you can add `-i` if you want to do it interactively.

Comment: Do you mean I should use `git rebase origin/master` instead of `git pull --rebase origin master`? I thought the former is a subset of the former but the latter does `git fetch` beforehand?

Comment: I wasn't trying to imply which one to use. I was just pointing out that the syntax for `pull` and `rebase` differ, as you noticed, and I was providing the correct syntax for rebase. Personally I prefer to regularly `git fetch` so I can see what's new before I use it, and then I would follow it with `git rebase origin/master`, but you save a few keystrokes doing it all in one shot with pull.

Answer (score 0):

The `git pull` command is quite different from most other Git commands.  I'd say that in many ways, the closest other Git command is `git gc`, which—like `git pull`—is a convenience wrapper to avoid needing to type in multiple separate Git commands.<sup>1</sup>

What `git pull` *does* is:

1. run `git fetch`; then
2. run a second Git command.

The first command, `git fetch`, needs the name of a *remote*.  The name `origin` is the standard name for the first remote, and since most Git repositories only have *one* remote, `origin` is the name for the first, last, and only remote in that repository.

You can leave this off—you can run `git pull` with no additional arguments—and Git will figure out some appropriate remote.  But if you're going to supply additional arguments, the first non-option argument *is* the remote name, so `git pull frabjous` uses the word `frabjous` as the name of the remote.

The *second* command is either `git merge` or `git rebase`.<sup>2</sup>  This *second* command needs a *commit hash ID*, such as `4c53a8c20f8984adb226293a3ffd7b88c3f4ac1a`, or something that will work in place of a commit hash ID.<sup>3</sup>  Usually, though, we use a *name*—a branch name like `master` or `main`, or `dev`, or whatever—as the "something that will work" here.  **The general idea—the way to think of `git pull`—is: *get stuff from the other guy, then incorporate it*.**  The "other guy" here is the *remote*, and the "stuff to get" is "any new commits he has on some branch of his".  So the *name you put in here*, when you put in a name, is *the other guy's branch name*.

Note that, as with `git fetch`, you can leave all of this out, and just run:

```
git pull
```

The pull command will figure out a *remote* to use—probably `origin`—and a *name* to use, all on its own, based on the *upstream* that you have set for the current branch.  The "upstream" is just a thing-you-can-set: for your branch named `xyzzy`, the upstream is probably *already set* to `origin/xyzzy`.

Note that the *upstream* name here, `origin/xyzzy`, has a slash in it: it's made up of the name of the *remote*, `origin`, then a slash, then the *branch name as seen on the remote*, `xyzzy`.  So if the branch name *as seen on the remote* is `frab/jous`, you'd have `origin/frab/jous` here, with two slashes: one to separate `origin` from the other guy's branch name, and one *in* the other guy's branch name.

If you're going to put in a name at all, on your `git pull` command, you *must place this after the remote*.  Having done that, Git assumes you'll just put in the branch name *as seen on the remote*.  So you type in:

```
git pull origin frab/jous
```

or whatever here, to mean:

1. run `git fetch origin`; then
2. resolve `origin/frab/jous` to a hash ID and run `git merge` or `git rebase` as appropriate.

Note that either of these two steps can *fail entirely*, and the second one can *stop in the middle*.  If one step fails, any remaining steps don't happen at all, and you should restart from the failed point, whatever that was, if you want to pick up where it left off—so you need to know which step failed, if one fails.  Luckily for most of us, `git fetch` is very safe to run an *extra time* so we can mostly just ignore its failure-vs-success.  But you still need to know whether to finish a stopped-in-the-middle merge or rebase.  For this and other reasons, I always encourage Git newbies to learn the separate commands *first*.  Recognizing when they've worked, when they've failed completely, and when they have stopped in the middle is important.

Unfortunately, that means you need to learn that oddity, where `git pull` takes the *other guy's name* for the branch (leaving out the `origin/`), and `git merge` or `git rebase` takes *your* name (including the `origin/`).  But you were going to have to learn this anyway.  Make a note of it!  *Their* branch names are theirs; *your* Git repository reads their name-and-hash-ID values from them (during the `git fetch` step), and stores them in *your* Git repository under these `origin/`-prefixed names.

This is still leaving out a *lot*.  Git has a very steep setup learning curve.  I'll take a break now for footnotes and then address one other thing.

---

<sup>1</sup>`git gc` runs `git repack`, `git prune-packed`, `git reflog expire`, `git worktree prune`, `git prune`, `git pack-refs`, and/or `git rerere gc` if/as appropriate.  This isn't meant to be a completely exhaustive list as the list has changed at times (e.g., `git worktree` didn't exist before Git 2.5) and I don't really keep track.  I generated this list by glancing over [the `git gc` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc).  I think this particular manual page might have been the main inspiration for https://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/

<sup>2</sup>There are a few special-case exceptions, including doing nothing at all if the `git fetch` step *fails*.

<sup>3</sup>This is a bit of an oversimplification, as `git merge` and `git rebase` can take more than one hash ID, and for a case that is never used by `git pull`, `git rebase` also requires a branch name.  For the purpose of being run *by* `git pull`, though, they wind up using hash IDs here.

---

#### `origin` is both a remote and ... well...

> But why is it that
>
> ```
> git rebase -i origin
> ```
>
> works?

Here's where another piece of the steep learning curve whacks you in the face.

Git is, in the end, all about *commits*.  The commits in the repository are the reason for using Git.  The individual commits are numbered, but the numbers themselves are big, ugly, random-looking things that are completely unsuited for humans.  These are the hash IDs or Object IDs, that spill out from `git log` for instance.  They're only really usable via cut-and-paste, so we mostly don't use them after all: we use *names*.

As a result, Git provides not one but *two* [key-value databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database).  One of these is indexed by the hash IDs, and that's how Git gains access to its commits and other internal data.  Git puts in a hash ID, and gets the commit or other object whose key is that particular hash ID.  When the object is a commit object, that represents a full snapshot of every file, frozen for all time in the form it had at the time you (or whoever) made the commit.

To *find* the hash ID, though, Git keeps a second database where the keys are names: branch names, tag names, and other sorts of names.  The branch names, like `master` or `main`, `dev` or `develop`, `frab/jous`, and so on, are up to you: you can choose any name you like (although it's wise to stick in a dash or slash or letter outside the [0-9a-f] set, because the "names" `cafebabe` and `badf00d` and `deadcab` *could* be abbreviated hash IDs).  To keep branch and tag names from bumping into each other, Git actually sticks `refs/heads/` in front of each *branch* name, and `refs/tags/` in front of each *tag* name.

The names that Git stores in your repository, so as to remember some other Git repository's *branch* names, are *remote-tracking names* (Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*) and are actually prefixed with `refs/remotes/`, so rather than `origin/dev`, these are really `refs/remotes/origin/dev`.

All of these names, in these various [*namespaces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace), hold one hash ID each.  That's all Git needs, because commits themselves *also* hold *other* commit hash IDs.  From one commit, Git can find another one.  From there, Git can find yet another commit—and so on, and on.  Git simply defines a *branch* name as "this name holds the hash ID of the commit that is to be called the *latest* on this branch".

So, if you're on some branch `main`, the *name* holds some hash ID `H`, which is the hash ID of some commit:

```
            <-H   <-- main
```

Each *commit* holds a list of previous-commit hash IDs, usually just one entry long, along with the snapshot of all files.  That's the backwards-pointing arrow coming out of `H`, here.  Commit `H` holds the hash ID of some earlier commit.  Let's call that one `G` and draw it in:

```
        <-G <-H   <-- main
```

Of course, `G` is a commit with a snapshot and another backwards arrow, so it must point to some earlier commit, which repeats over and over:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- main
```

and that's a Git branch.  To add a commit *to* a branch, we "check it out" or "switch to it" by name, making the *name* the *current branch name* and the corresponding commit `H` the *current commit*.

We can have *more than one name* pointing to this commit.  Let's draw in several names: `main` and `dev` and also `origin/main`, which isn't a *branch* name but still points to a commit.  For laziness I'll stop bothering with arrows between commits, but remember that Git only works backwards, never forwards:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- dev, main, origin/main
```

We pick one branch—let's say `dev`—to switch to.  To remember that we're using the name `dev`, we attach the special name `HEAD` to it:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- dev (HEAD), main, origin/main
```

Now we fiddle around the way we do with Git—which I won't cover here but the index or staging area (two terms for the same thing) is crucial—and eventually make some new commit.  The new commit, which we'll call `I`, has a new unique hash ID and points backwards to existing commit `H`, like this:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I
```

The tricky bit is that Git updates the *current branch name* as soon as it has finished making new commit `I`.  None of the *other* names are updated, so they all still point to `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
            \
             I   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

Commit `I` is now the *latest* commit on `dev`.  Commits up through `H` are still on `dev`, and continue to be on `main` as well.  The special name `HEAD` is still attached to `dev`, and our current *commit* is now commit `I`.  Commit `H` still exists (and, crucially for Git's hashing scheme, is *completely untouched:* this is why the arrows all go backwards, not forwards).

Okay, but—so what?  Well, Git is, as I said earlier, all about the *commits*.  When you give Git a branch name, most of the time it very quickly turns that name into a hash ID by figuring out where the name points.  (The `git switch` and `git checkout` commands are unusual here in that they have to remember the *name*, too, so that you can become "on" that branch when they're done.)  There's a command-line Git command that does this for you, namely `git rev-parse`.  If we give `git rev-parse` some branch names, we can see it in action:

```
$ git rev-parse master
5d01301f2b865aa8dba1654d3f447ce9d21db0b5
$ git rev-parse diff-merge-base
fa1c8acabf0d5649baf87f549d67426d14255e0f
```

It can parse tag names too though, and remote-tracking names, and with `--symbolic-full-name` it can tell us what the full spelling of each name is:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name v2.35.1
refs/tags/v2.35.1
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name origin/master
refs/remotes/origin/master
$ git rev-parse origin/master
5d01301f2b865aa8dba1654d3f447ce9d21db0b5
```

What happens if we give it `origin` alone?

```
$ git rev-parse origin
5d01301f2b865aa8dba1654d3f447ce9d21db0b5
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name origin
refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Well, that's a bit peculiar, isn't it?  Let's take a look at [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), which is crucially important and cleverly hidden in plain sight in a pile of 1000 largely unreadable manual pages:

> **SPECIFYING REVISIONS**
> ...
> `<refname> e.g., master, heads/master, refs/heads/master`
> ... a `<refname>` is disambiguated by taking the first match in the following rules:
>
> 1. If `$GIT_DIR/<refname>` exists, that is what you mean (this is usually useful only for `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD` and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`);
> 2. otherwise, `refs/<refname>` if it exists;
> 3. otherwise, `refs/tags/<refname>` if it exists;
> 4. otherwise, `refs/heads/<refname>` if it exists;
> 5. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>` if it exists;
> 6. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD` if it exists.

It's this six-step rule that makes name abbreviations work.  We write:

```
git rebase master
```

and Git tries `master` as a file in `.git` (step 1), but that doesn't exist, so Git goes on to try `refs/master` as a name (step 2).  That doesn't exist either so Git tries `refs/heads/master` as a name (step 3).  That one *does* exist, in this repository anyway, so it resolves to a hash ID and the revision specifying is complete.

If we use `origin/master`, step 5 finds it, because `refs/remotes/origin/master` exists (use `git for-each-ref` to dump out the ref table, and see that it does exist).  And if we use `origin`—which doesn't seem to be a ref-name at all—step *6* finds it, because `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` exists.

Now, `HEAD`—and correspondingly, `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`—is a special case: it's a *symbolic* reference, which in Git is analogous to a symbolic link in Unix/Linux file systems.  (In fact, in early Git implementations, it simply *was* a symbolic link.  That does not work well on Windows though, so now it's a file with contents.)  The `git for-each-ref` command expands the link by default, but `git branch -r` doesn't, so that's one way to see this.

#### The bottom line

The conclusion of all of this is:

1. `origin/HEAD` is a symbolic ref for whatever branch is the `HEAD` in `origin`, usually `master` or `main`;
2. `origin` by itself is either a *remote* (as used by `git fetch`), or resolvable via step 6 of gitrevisions (as used by most other Git commands);
3. `git rebase -i origin` resolves it via `origin/HEAD` and step 6; but
4. `git pull origin master` doesn't use step 6 at all: the string `origin` is just a *remote*, and the string `master` gets mapped through the remote-tracking names to become `origin/master` (and in this particular case `git pull` actually sidesteps all this because it's using the `.git/FETCH_HEAD` file mechanisms, which predate all this stuff and go through somewhat different code paths).

The `git pull` command passes most of its flags and arguments on to `git fetch`, except for some flags that it passes to the second command, and some flags that it uses itself.  It's enormously complicated because of historical ... mistakes? ideas? concepts? anyway, history of the way Git *used to work*, which must be preserved in amber for the next 300 million years, or whatever.  (Seriously though, the Git folks take compatibility itself quite seriously and try not to break existing uses and workflows.)